# getproperty value ksoap2 android

Tags: android, soap, ksoap2

```
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION + GetPersonnel_METHOD, envelope);
SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
```

This is the soap response I got

```
anyType{EntityKey=anyType{EntityContainerName=DSS_SOTUBIEntities;
EntityKeyValues=anyType{EntityKeyMember=anyType{Key=PersonnelID; Value=2; }; }; 
EntitySetName=Personnels; }; Adresse=ariana; CAB=784555584; CodeCommande=1; CommandeID=5;
 CommercialID=2; DateCreation=2013-12-13T00:00:00;
```

View Properties

```
String res=null;
SoapObject pii = (SoapObject)result.getProperty(0);
res = pii;
```

res displays the following result:

```
anyType{EntityContainerName=DSS_SOTUBIEntities;
EntityKeyValues=anyType{EntityKeyMember=anyType{Key=PersonnelID; Value=2; }; }; 
EntitySetName=Personnels;
```

and for getProperty(1)

```
SoapObject pii = (SoapObject)result.getProperty(1);
```

res show"undefined"

how to recuper the value of  Adresse,CAB, CodeCommande...

Thanx for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SoapObject Address = (SoapObject)result.getProperty("Adresse");
```

You miss a closing bracket in your soap Response. I assumed it is at the end of the response.

If it is not working check the number of Properties available using

```
response.getPropertyCount();
```